# Swap linkedlist nodes

Tags: java

I am trying to solve a question asked in a interview to swap two nodes in a linkedlist. I happened to find the solution for the answer posted online.

```
public static void searchNode(int dataX, int dataY, Node head) {
    Node currentDataX = head, prevDataX = null;

    while (currentDataX != null && currentDataX.data != dataX) {
        prevDataX = currentDataX;
        currentDataX = currentDataX.next;
    }

    Node currentDataY = head, prevDataY = null;

    while (currentDataY != null && currentDataY.data != dataY) {
        prevDataY = currentDataY;
        currentDataY = currentDataY.next;
    }

    if (prevDataX == null) {
        head = currentDataX;
    }else {
        prevDataX.next = currentDataY;
    }

    if (prevDataY == null) {
        head = currentDataY;
    }else {
        prevDataY.next = currentDataX;
    }

    // Swap next pointers
    Node temp = currentDataY.next;
    currentDataY.next = currentDataX.next;
    currentDataX.next = temp;
}
```

The solution is very clear to me except I don't understand the else cases where prevDataX and prevDataY are null. Why are we doing prevDataX.next = currentDataY, and prevDataX.next = currentDataY when we are executing a swap in the end anyway.

Comment: In the general case, 4 next pointers need to change. Two of them contained in the objects pointing to X and Y (those are the else statements), and the other two in X and Y (those are the final swap).

Comment: Is it single linked or double linked list ?